# symfony 2.3 clear cache command takes a long time

Tags: symfony

when I remove the cache **it takes too much time** because my cache folders are large.
folder size in three days :

```
$ du -sh app/cache/*
2.6M    app/cache/dev
46M     app/cache/prod
363M    app/cache/prod_old
```

how to speed up this process ?

Comment: Simply try this `rm -rf app/cache/*`

Comment: Afaik, the clear cache command does a cache warmup afterwards, which is why it takes longer than simply removing as Matteo stated.

Comment: If you don't want to remove the entire cache from simply removing the files, you can do `php app/console cache:clear --no-optional-warmers` or `php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup`

Comment: How do high traffic sites? this command must take hours for each release !

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this to the point where it would take over an hour to clear after deploying a new build - totally unacceptable.

I found that I could move the cache out first (move operations are quick), run symfony cc, then delete the cache afterwards without impacting the site.

```
mv app/cache/* /tmp
./symfony cc
rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Comment: OK good idea vgan, I will try this process as quickly as possible. Thanks

Comment: in my case move operations are not so fast as you say.

Comment: @stloc if its on the same file system, a move operation just changes the pointers to the file so it should be immediate.  maybe you are moving between volumes or a remote mount?